# Django middleware for consuming an external api

Tags: django, python-3.x

Here's the deal, I need to consume an API and every time I perform a request a header needs to be appended, I've checked the [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/)
but this is only working for incoming requests, is there anything that can be used in this situation.

Comment: how are you consuming the API?

Comment: I'm importing `requests` and consuming  like this `requests.get('api/url', headers=custom_header)`

Comment: why don't you pass within `custom_header` the header that you need?

Comment: actually that's what I have been doing, but since I have to do several requests I was wondering if there was any way to append the header automatically every time I call the api.

Comment: you can create a dumb API Client using python classes that does it one time for you.

Comment: Do you think is there any way the job could be done with a middleware?

Comment: No. Middlewares are used for the requests coming in to django, and the responses coming out. Not during the calling of external services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments:

```
class ServiceAPIClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = "http://example.com/api"
        self.custom_header = "custom: header example"

    def consume_endpoint(self, endpoint):
        return requests.get(self.base_url+endpoint, headers=self.custom_header)
```

And then use it inside your views/models like:

```
response = ServiceAPIClient().consume_endpoint("/endpoint")
```

Take in mind that this is a silly example...